# Unordered List (UL) expands layout when text breaks in multiple lines

Tags: css, html-lists

My UL expands my fixed-width layout when text breaks into multiple lines, in Chrome and Firefox. I've tried to resolve this through CSS, I've tried the INSIDE option, also constrained the WIDTH of both UL and LI, but it didn't work. My layout is 600px, but ***width: 600px;*** will still expand my layout if text breaks. Also ***width: 500px;*** still expands my layout. Only if I reduce to ***width: 300px;*** the layout is not expanded, but I can't work with such narrow width. Is this a bug of some browsers or anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a simple CSS fix, could you please post your code to have a look at?

Comment: I apologize, I just found what the problem was, it was related to the vertical scrollbar appearing, nothing to do with UL.